# Getting Wikipedia API

Tags: php, json, api, wikipedia

I'm trying to retrieve json data from the wikipedia API for my Website

To retrieve json data from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=facebook

We must also attach a pageid, while each content has a different pageid

Whatsapp on Wikipedia has a pageid: **686916**

Facebook on Wikipedia has a pageid: **221230**

And other content has a different pageid

Meanwhile, to retrieve data from wikipedia api must include a pageid

How do I solve it?

```
$ua = array();
  $ua[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0';
  $ua[] = 'content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8';
  
  $data = json_decode(get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=$query",$ua),true);

  $getdata = $data["query"]["pages"]["pageidhere"]["extract"];
```

If in Python, to find the pageid using the following logic

```
kya = request.args.get('q')
            cih = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles={kya}'
            heuh = get(cih).json()
            heuh_ = heuh['query']['pages']
            hueh = re.findall(r'(\d+)', str(heuh_))
            result = heuh_[hueh[0]]['extract']:
```

Look at the following line:

```
heuh_ = heuh['query']['pages']
hueh = re.findall(r'(\d+)', str(heuh_))
```

Then how do I implement it in PHP?

Comment: I know I am supposed to know, but where does `get()` come from

Comment: I have function there, back to the problem, how do I get the pageid? while each content has a different pageid, If in Python, to find the pageid using the following logic

kya = request.args.get('q')
   cih = f'https://id.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles={kya}'
   heuh = get(cih).json()
   heuh_ = heuh['query']['pages']
   hueh = re.findall(r'(\d+)', str(heuh_))
   result = heuh_[hueh[0]]['extract']:

Comment: Seems like you would need to prepare a list of all the page ids you want to retreieve and do a separate API call for each of them.

Comment: Get all page ids? but it doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. So, what troubles you is just how to extract the value because you don't know the key?

Comment: I asked what `get()` was so I could attempt to test some code, but back to the problem !!

Comment: function get($url,$header){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

Comment: [Loop it](https://3v4l.org/tTYKS)?

Comment: Other options come to mind, like using `array_keys` on `$data["query"]["pages"]`.

Comment: _Small Point_ A `curl_close($ch);` AFTER a RETURN is a bit late to try and close the curl connection, as it will never be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother you but you could do this

```
$ua = array();
$ua[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0';
$ua[] = 'content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8';
  
$data = json_decode(get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=$query",$ua));

foreach ($data->query->pages as $pid) {
    echo 'Your pageid = ' . $pid->pageid . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Title = ' .  $pid->title . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'extract = ' .  $pid->extract . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
Your pageid = 7529378
Title = Facebook
extract = Facebook (stylized as facebook) is an American online social media and social networking service based in Menlo Park, California, and a flagship service of the namesake company Facebook, Inc. It was founded by Mark Zuckerberg, along with fellow Harvard College students and roommates Eduardo Saverin, Andrew McCollum, Dustin Moskovitz, and Chris Hughes.
The founders of Facebook initially limited membership to Harvard students. Membership was expanded to Columbia, Stanford, and Yale before being expanded to the rest of the Ivy League, MIT, and higher education institutions in the Boston area, then various other universities, and lastly high school students. Since 2006, anyone who claims to be at least 13 years old has been allowed to become a registered user of Facebook, though this may vary depending on local laws. The name comes from the face book directories often given to American university students.
Facebook can be accessed from devices with Internet connectivity, such as personal computers, tablets and smartphones. After registering, users can create a profile revealing information about themselves. They can post text, photos and multimedia which is shared with any other users that have agreed to be their "friend", or, with a different privacy setting, with any reader. Users can also use various embedded apps, join common-interest groups, buy and sell items or services on Marketplace, and receive notifications of their Facebook friends' activities and activities of Facebook pages they follow. Facebook claimed that it had 2.74 billion monthly active users as of September 2020, and it was the most downloaded mobile app of the 2010s globally.Facebook has been the subject of numerous controversies, often involving user privacy (as with the Cambridge Analytica data scandal), political manipulation (as with the 2016 U.S. elections), mass surveillance, psychological effects such as addiction and low self-esteem, and content such as fake news, conspiracy theories, copyright infringement, and hate speech. Commentators have accused Facebook of willingly facilitating the spread of such content and also exaggerating its number of users in order to appeal to advertisers. As of January 21, 2021, Alexa Internet ranks Facebook seventh in global internet usage.
```

Note: I removed the `,true` so the json object gets converted to a PHP object

OR simply

```
echo 'PageId = ' . array_keys((array)$data->query->pages)[0];
```

Comment: OMG this helps me in getting the pageid

But how do I print "extract" and "title"

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been resolved.